# Impossible to force www URL in HTTPS

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite, https

I am trying to redirect all incoming requests in my site to: `https://www.example.com`

I am able to redirect HTTP traffic, with and without www, but I cannot get it to work with non-www HTTPS requests. I mean:

- `http://example.com` -> redirects correctly
- `http://www.example.com` -> redirects correctly
- `https://example.com` -> DOES NOT REDIRECT

I have tried many rules in my `.htaccess` file but none of them seem to work.

I am using Apache/2.2.15 on a CentOS machine. I also use mod_jk module to redirect all traffic to Tomcat.

My configuration files look as follow:

**mod_jk.conf**

```
LoadModule jk_module "/etc/httpd/modules/mod_jk.so"
JkWorkersFile /etc/httpd/conf/workers.properties
JkShmFile     /var/run/httpd/mod_jk.shm
JkLogFile     /var/log/httpd/mod_jk.log
JkLogLevel    info
JkLogStampFormat "[%a %b %d %H:%M:%S %Y] "
```

**workers.properties**

```
workers.apache_log=/var/log/httpd
worker.list=app1Worker
worker.app1Worker.type=ajp13
worker.app1Worker.host=localhost
worker.app1Worker.port=8009
```

**app1.conf**

```
<VirtualHost *:443>
    ServerName example.com
    ServerAlias www.example.com
    LogFormat "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %b \"%{Referer}i\" \"%{User-agent}i\"" combined
    CustomLog /var/log/httpd/app1_access.log combined
    ErrorLog /var/log/httpd/app1_error.log

    #<IfModule mod_jk.c>
       JkMount /* app1Worker
    #</IfModule>

    SSLEngine on
    SSLCertificateFile    /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/cert.pem
    SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/privkey.pem
    SSLCertificateChainFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/chain.pem
</VirtualHost>
```

**listening.conf**

```
Listen 217.61.129.109:80
Listen 217.61.129.109:443
```

**.htaccess**

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://www.example.com%{REQUEST_URI} [L,NE,R=301]
```

I have tried many other rules in the `.htaccess` file but none of them have worked.

Could you tell the reason the last case is not working?

**UPDATE-1**

Sorry for the misunderstanding but I had only included parentheses because StackOverflow complained otherwise. Just ignore them. *(Now removed)*

The configuration of `AllowOverride` is in the main `httpd.conf` file of Apache:

```
DocumentRoot "/var/www/html"
<Directory />
    Options SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
    AllowOverride All
</Directory>

<Directory "/var/www/html">
    Options Indexes SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
    AllowOverride All
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
</Directory>
```

I changed `AllowOverride None` by `AllowOverride All` because in the beginning this was the reason, `.htaccess` file was not processed at all.

Now I have tested that this file is being processed because if I comment all its content then HTTP redirection doesn't work. My problem is only with non-www HTTPS redirection.

My feeling is that rules in `.htaccess` are correct but there must be something else I am missing.

**UPDATE-2 SOLVED!!!**

Look below for the answer

Comment: Where are you enabling `.htaccess` in your https config? (ie. `AllowOverride` directive). Since the parenthesis around the protocol would break this redirect _horribly_, I suspect it's not being executed at all. However, since you have access to the server-config, you should be doing this redirect there, rather than `.htaccess`. Then your VirtualHost for port 80 would have a simple `Redirect`. Create a separate VirtualHost just for your canonical host and `Redirect` to it. And, as always, clear your browser cache.

Comment: I have updated my post, please check. I have tried to do that redirect on VirtualHost and it works to redirect http traffic from port 80 to https. But how can I force there www for https urls?

Comment: You should add your "**UPDATE-2**" as an answer and accept it (I'll upvote it! :) Incidentally, the parentheses are not required if you format as code (either inline or block) - I've edited to remove them (they are misleading).

Comment: It's done. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**SOLVED!!!**

Well I don't now why .htaccess filters didn't work for the special case mentioned but as per @MrWhite advice I get it to work with `<VirtualHost>` configurations.

I updated my listening.conf file like this:

```
NameVirtualHost *:80
Listen 80
NameVirtualHost *:443
Listen 443
```

And my app1.conf like this:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
   ServerName www.example.com
   ServerAlias example.com
   Redirect permanent / https://www.example.com/
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:443>
   ServerName example.com
   Redirect permanent / https://www.example.com/
   SSLEngine on
   SSLCertificateFile    /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/cert.pem
   SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/privkey.pem
   SSLCertificateChainFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/chain.pem

</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:443>
    ServerName www.example.com
    LogFormat "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %b \"%{Referer}i\" \"%{User-agent}i\"" combined
    CustomLog /var/log/httpd/app1_access.log combined
    ErrorLog /var/log/httpd/app1_error.log
    #Redirect all traffic to Tomcat
    JkMount /* app1Worker
    SSLEngine on
    SSLCertificateFile    /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/cert.pem
    SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/privkey.pem
    SSLCertificateChainFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/chain.pem
</VirtualHost>
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Thank you so much for coming back and posting your solution. This helped greatly. :) +1